# Is it possible to use InetAccessHandler in Jetty along with X-Forwarded-For header?

Tags: jetty, load-balancing, whitelist

I have a situation where I am using Jetty to limit IP’s using `InetAccessHandler`; however, the load balancer is passing in the main IP address as the source instead of the actual client.

Is there a way to use the actual client address instead of the load balancer’s when filtering on this utility?

The load balancer is sending the actual IP address in the `X-Forwarded-For` header. Is there some way to make that plugin use this instead of the actual ip address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the `ForwardingRequestCustomizer` in your `HttpConfiguration` associated with the connector.

That will adjust the internal authority on the request to fit the information passed on the `X-Forwarding-For` headers. (including the request.remoteAddr)

Also consider using the official `Forwarding` header ([RFC7239](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7239)) as it is far better supported then then non-standard `X-Forwarding-*` headers (that often conflict with each other).